# DOMDocument saveHTML with wrong output

Tags: php, domdocument

I have this simple code:

```
$input = '<p>ěščřžýáíé</p><p><img alt="" src="http://www.test.com/img.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$dom->loadHTML($input, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgs as $img){
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    $style = $img->getAttribute('style');
    $newSrc = 'http://www.test.com/img001.jpg';
    $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $newSrc );
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Problem is that output is encoded.
I expect same characters as are on input.
I tried decoding without success. Something wrong with using DOM object?

```
<p>&Auml;&#155;&Aring;&iexcl;&Auml;&#141;&Aring;&#153;&Aring;&frac34;&Atilde;&frac12;&Atilde;&iexcl;&Atilde;&shy;&Atilde;&copy;<p><img alt="" src="http://www.test.com/img001.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></p></p>
```

Comment: The output is encoded in what way? url encoded, character entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveHTML()` has a few 'features' which I don't understand, but when saving with a particular document node it will work if you then `utf8_decode()` the result...

```
$content = utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

gives...

```
<p>ěščřžýáíé<p><img alt="" src="http://www.test.com/img001.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></p></p>
```